# replacement using function instead of regex

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I found the following code in a book:

Previous example:

```
'iixxxixx'.replace(/i+/g,'($1)')
```

Next example:

You can also compute a replacement via a function:

```
function repl(all){
  return '('+all.toUpperCase()+')'
}
'axbbyyxaa'.repl(/a+|b+/g,replacement)
//logs ' (A) x (BB) yyx (AA) '
```

replacement may be like ($1)

But when I tested it is returning undefined is not a function.

I think something missing, what is the correct way to do?

Comment: This piece of code does not make sense. Are you sure you typed it correctly from that book? Which book is it?

Comment: This code does not run properly and does not make sense too. please post a proper block.

Comment: do you mean replace: `'axbbyyxaa'.replace(/a+|b+/g,repl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your book says

```
function repl(all){
  return '(' + all.toUpperCase() + ')';
}

'axbbyyxaa'.replace(/a+|b+/g, repl);

//logs '(A)x(BB)yyx(AA)'
```

Comment: oh! I just got it now. Thanks.